# changing color of google map api v2

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I change the color of direction line in google map api I checked the gdriection,but there's nothing about color this is my code

```
function direction() 
{
    var txtAddress = document.getElementById("<%=txtAddress.ClientID %>");

    var address = txtAddress.value;

    var TextBox1 = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>");

    var address1 = TextBox1.value;

    directions = new GDirections(map, directionsPanel);
    directions.load("from: " + address1 + " to: " + address + "");

  //  var address =txtAddress.value + "  " + TextBox3.value;

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See this similar answer on the Maps Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-maps-api/-1yGOmMwd7I

Seems you can't change the colour after instantiating the `GPolyLine`, so you need to build two `GPolyLine`s and add/remove them from the overlay to display a different colour.

Without knowing any better, a way of doing it would be:

1. Don't pass the `GDirections` constructor a `GMap`, so it doesn't add
   any `GPolyLine`s
2. Build an array of `GLatLng` vertices from
   `GDirections.getVertex(index)`
3. Build your own `GPolyLine`s with
   different colours
4. Overlay the `GPolyLine` on the map with
   `GMap2.addOverlay(GOverlay)`

Comment: I've this code                                        `GEvent.addListener(dirn,"load", function() { 
        var poly=dirn.getPolyline(); 
        setTimeout("map.removeOverlay(dirn.getPolyline())",1); 
        var points = []; 
        for (var i=0; i<poly.getVertexCount(); i++) { 
          points.push(poly.getVertex(i)); 
        } 
        map.addOverlay(new GPolyline(points, "#ff0000",5,1)); 
      });`                                                         How can I use it in mine?